# What were standard university texts in algebra in the mid 19th century?

Tags: reference-request, teaching

Dedekind in 1872 wrote that equations like  $\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$ ``to the best of my knowledge have never been established before'' (*Continuity and Irrational Numbers*, p. 22).  This was not a crazy thing to say but it makes me wonder what were the standard textbook treatments at the time.  A book like Rouse Ball *History of the Study of Mathematics at Cambridge* would be ideal for this question, except that it's account of instruction ends with the 18th century and it covers the 19th century only in  connection with the Tripos.

Comment: I'd think that there was no notion of "algebra" in the mid 19th century in Europe. That is, although Vandermonde and Lagrange (pre-1800) knew how to solve many equations in radicals (when they were so-solvable), it seems to have been by seat-of-the-pants algebra, not formal/axiomatic/formal. It is my impression that Euler effectively operated this way, as well.

Comment: @paulgarrett In the 1820s Bewick Bridge published several editons of a textbook titled *A treatise on the elements of algebra*.  George  Peacock, George has a famous 1830 *Treatise on Algebra*.  It is true that so far as can think of right off hand continental authors were more likely to put this kind of algebra in books with titles like *Analysis*.  But it is there.  Or did you only mean they did not have 20th century style formally axiomatized algebra?

Comment: It is my impression that "rules of algebra" were considered _descriptive_ of palpable realities.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of early 19<sup>th</sup> century textbooks (from [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/986254/128568)):

Cauchy entered the *lycée* ("high school") *École Centrale du Panthéon* in 1802, studying humanities. Then, in 1805 he entered the *École Polytechnique* at age 15.

The "core" mathematics curriculum at the *École Polytechnique* was:

> **Analysis instruction**: the *Cours d'Analyse Algébrique* by Garnier and
>   the *[Traité Élémentaire de Calcul Différentiel et Intégral](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6213792j)* by
>   Lacroix;
>
> **Mechanics instruction**: the *Traité de Mécanique*, using the methods of Prony and edited by Francoeur and the *Plan Raisonne du Cours de Prony*;
>
> **Descriptive geometry instruction**: the *[Géométrie Descriptive](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433057782298;view=1up;seq=13)* by Monge;
>
> **Applied analysis instruction**: the *Feuilles d'Analyse Appliquée a la
>   Géométrie* by Monge and the *Application de l’Algèbre à la Géométrie*
>   by Monge and Hachette.

(Belhoste, Bruno. *[Augustin-Louis Cauchy: A Biography](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-2996-4)*. New York: Springer-Verlag, 1991. pp. 7-10. Appendix II is Cauchy's outlines of his analysis courses he taught at the *École Polytechnique* from 1816-1819.

See [the distribution of courses at the École Polytechnique when Cauchy was a student there](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044079809943;view=1up;seq=400).)

Comment: A good list.  These books all take the algebra of roots entirely for granted.

Comment: @Colin What do you mean by "the algebra of roots"? And why do they take it "entirely for granted"?

Comment: These texts all note things like $\sqrt[n]{a}\times\sqrt[n]{b}=\sqrt[n]{ab}$, and $\sqrt[n]{\sqrt[m]{a}}=\sqrt[nm]{a}$.  But they rarely comment in any way on the idea of proving such equations.  The equations are simply taken for granted. As to why they do that, I have some ideas but do not really know.  They seem to think it is just a consequence of the notation.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty Do they mention it being an axiom?

Comment: No, that language was seriously not current at that time.  Axioms were for geometry.  And no one that I have found makes any effort to pick out a group of equations to assume, while deriving others from them.  Some say that such calculations are "convenient."  Basically, I think Dedekind was right, but I'm not certain he was.